# How to Upgrade Custom Module in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, magento-upgrade

I am using `Magento 2.2.3` currently, and i have created many custom modules. Now i am planing to upgrade my site with `Magento 2.3.2`. So i have no idea how can i upgrade my custom modules. I am very new to magento 2.3 . I mean what kind of code changes require to make compatiable my custom module with `Magento 2.3`. Any help?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Why you also want to upgrade your custum modules with Magento upgrade ? these modules don't work anymore when you made the Magento upgrade to 2.3.2 ?

Comment: @PЯINCƏ : I mean, i want my custom functionality will be work after the upgrade also thats why i want to change code of my custom module according to Magento 2.3.

Comment: I don't know what was changed in `2.3.2` but you look if after the upgrade your modules doesn't work, you see the errors then you solve them, I don't see other solution. Don't forget to the a backup before.

Comment: okay @PЯINCƏ , Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can find M2.3 modules that have similar function as those you used in Magento 2.2 and use an migration tool to import data from your one module to the new one.